# Magento 2.3.1 add custom attribute to customer

Tags: custom-attributes, customer-attribute

I have follow several guide or tutorial but I can't understand how insert a custom attribute to customer general info, specifically I would to insert a second email field.

Actually I've the following structure

```
src/app/code/
|-- Vendor_Name
|   |-- CustomerAttribute
|   |   |-- registration.php
|   |   |-- etc
|   |   |   |-- module.xml
|   |   |   |-- extension_attributes.xml
|   |   |   |-- Setup
|   |   |   |   |-- Patch
|   |   |   |   |   |-- Data
|   |   |   |   |   |   | -- AddCustomerAccountCode.php
```

**AddCustomerAccountCode.php** contains the following code

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\CustomerAttribute\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\Patch\Data\UpdateIdentifierCustomerAttributesVisibility;

class AddCustomerAccountCode implements DataPatchInterface
{
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    private $customerSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }


    public function apply()
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'email_agent', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Email Agente',
            'input' => 'text',
            'sort_order' => 100,
            'position' => 100,
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'system' => false
        ]);
        $customerAccountCode =$customerSetup->getEavConfig()->clear()
            ->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'email_agent');


        if ($customerAccountCode->getAttributeId()) {
            $usedInForms =  ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_create'];
            $data = [];
            foreach ($usedInForms as $formCode) {
                $data[] = ['form_code' => $formCode, 'attribute_id' => $customerAccountCode->getAttributeId()];
            }
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->insertMultiple(
                $this->moduleDataSetup->getTable('customer_form_attribute'),
                $data
            );
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
        }
     }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [
            UpdateIdentifierCustomerAttributesVisibility::class,
        ];
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

File **module.xml** into **etc** folder has these lines

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendoName_CustomerAttribute" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Where is the trick?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here goes

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "xigen/module-customer",
    "description": "",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "name",
            "email": "email@email.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Xigen\\Customer\\": ""
        },
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

registration.php

```php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Xigen_Customer',
    __DIR__
);
```

etc/extension_attributes.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface">
        <attribute code="second_email" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Xigen_Customer" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Setup/InstallData.php

```php
namespace Xigen\Customer\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'second_email', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Second Email',
            'input' => 'text',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'position' => 50,
            'system' => false,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'second_email')
        ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'adminhtml_checkout',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit'
            ]
        ]);
        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

Then the usual

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

Comment: Ok I get your code and at the end, before cleaning cache, I received this message on screen 

```Nothing to import.
Please re-run Magento compile command. Use the command "setup:di:compile"
```
I need to clean cache and redo compiling of static content to manage admin page but still nothing appears on customers form

Comment: In Magento 2 version information is stored on setup_module table. Check if there is any reference to your extension in there. Might need to use `php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Extension`